# Removing tags after reading PDF in R

Tags: r, pdf

I am reading PDF in Hebrew into R using textreadr::read_document, and getting tags which I can't remove, such as <U+202B>. Looking at the data in the console, the tags are absent; if I try to remove them using gsub or stringr::str_replace, nothing happens. However, they are clearly there (see image), and worse - if I export to Excel, they are exported as part of the data. What can I do?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like this: This code I used to replace non-ASCII characters.

```
library(textclean)
attach(CA_videos_df) ##data frame name
Encoding(title) <- "latin1"       ## title is data frame column name
name = replace_non_ascii(title,replacement = NA, remove.nonconverted = TRUE)  ## replacing title with non-ascii characters with NA
```